# using Vue v-for turns html code into a comment?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to use v-for to generate a number of divs, but no matter how many ways I have tried (I also have tried using it to iterate over a list, doesn't work either), the v-for is just not working as it should, and alway turn the line into a comment when it runs.

No error shown in console.

here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!--    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="game_board_block" v-for="num in 10">{{num}}</div>

<script language="JavaScript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried loading Vue by either of the https link, both work for other Vue directives(v-if, v-show etc.), so it shouldn't be the problem with loading Vue.

and here is the code in my game.js

```
var game_board_block = new Vue({
    el: "#game_board_block",
    data: {
        n: 5,
        list1: [5, 2, 0]
    }
});
```

** **By the way, why do I must put my own js script which bound the div to a Vue instance below the html code of that div?** I'm very new to Vue, I just know this can work, but I don't know why it works, I have tried to put it before the html code bounded to it, or in title area but none of them would work. And this is a little counterintuitive for me, I thought it would make more sense if I bound the element first before using it? Or is it the case that before the html code, that html element can be considered as "not exist", so there is no way to bound it to a Vue instance?

here is how the html elements look like when I open inspect elements of the browser:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXPyU.png)

I then tried replacing

```
<div id="game_board_block" v-for="num in 10">{{num}}</div>
```

with

```
<div id="game_board_block">
    <div v-for="num in 10">{{num}}</div>
</div>
```

and it does work as I expected, but I'm not sure why exactly that it can work now? Is it that v-for can't be used in the same element that bound to a Vue instance? It can only be in the child node of an element that bound to a Vue instance?

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
<div id="game_board_block" v-for="num in 10">{{num}}</div>
```

You're trying to loop & create multiple div elements with the same id. Since your Vue instance is linked to #game_board_block, there should only be one element with that id.

This is why this works:

```
<div id="game_board_block">
  <div v-for="num in 10">{{num}}</div>
</div>
```

Above, your Vue instance is able to mount on the div with id *game_board_block*.
Here's the official documentation for more details: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Creating-a-Vue-Instance

Answer (score 0):

you can't do anything weird with vue root even though i haven't tried it with vue3 root but i'm sure vue 2 requires a component to have only 1 node at root

Comment: on vue 3 something like v-for in component wrapper is valid because vue 3 already supports Fragments but vue 2 when not at least `Vue Naruto` or below

Comment: you have to put the script at the end of the body because then the specified root element will exist in the DOM if you don't want to put it below you can place it above with `new Vue` in the `load` event or `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining!! Your answer is very helpful and solves my confuse

Comment: vue 2 is outdated i recommend `vue 3 - Gotōbun no Hanayome` or `vue 2.7 - Naruto` to get the latest features

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some sense here.
The main problem is that your `<div>` is missing the `:key` prop.
A `v-for` should come with some unique key, so that Vue can differ between the rendered `div`s.
In Vue3 this problem doesn't result in an error, but still it's not recommended. So you should do the following:

```js
<div
  id="game_board_block"
  v-for="listItem in list1"
  :key="listItem.somethingUnique
>
  {{ listItem.content }}
</div>
```

Assuming your list1 has something to support what I did here:

```js
data: {
  n: 5,
  list1: [{
    somethingUnique: "index1",
    content: 5
  },
  {
    somethingUnique: "index2",
    content: 2
  },
  {
    somethingUnique: "index3",
    content: 0
  }]
}
```

---

Even though this should solve your problem, **using the same id is an anti-pattern that you should avoid**, as @Fred mentioned.

Making sure the ids stay unique is simple as well:

```js
<div
  :id="`game_board_block-${listItem.somethingUnique}`"
  v-for="listItem in list1"
  :key="listItem.somethingUnique
>
  {{ listItem.content }}
</div>
```